# How to click on a row by its text winapi

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I am trying to delete the pending order by SendKeys using UP and Down arrows.I just want to go directly to the row and delete it rather than making it to go down by pressing down array like this

```
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < Down; i2++)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{DELETE}");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
```

there are may be 1000 of rows for each and every row i cant go down and then click delete button i want to go directly to the row for deleting inspite of pressing down again and again.
There is a column called status,there are Executed,Pending and Cancelled rows so i just want to go to the Pending Row by its Exch Ord.NO column.

Here is the picture of the window i want to navigate directly to the row

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhd8o.jpg

and I've searched the window by Spy++ also and i've got this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sSpI.jpg

Hope everyone have understood my question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to control a separate application which you did not code?